# use derived class object in base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-base-class

I have a base class which contain helper method, and I have some derived classes which contain some virtual methods.

so, I want to know how can I use the derived class object in the base classes virtual methods?

derived class

```
 class myclass :baseClass
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

}
```

base class

```
public abstract class baseClass
{

    public virtual object FromStream()
    {
        string name, type;

        List<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(typeof(object).GetProperties()); // here I need to use derived class object 

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            type = prop.PropertyType.ToString();
            name = prop.Name;

            Console.WriteLine(name + " as "+ type);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

main

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myclass = new myclass();
        myclass.FromStream(); // the object that I want to use it 

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: "here I need to use derived class object" - what do you mean? I suspect you *may* just want to call `GetType().GetProperties()`. Btw, it's helpful to follow .NET naming conventions even for sample code - and to provide *complete* sample code. (Your `Main` method is in an undeclared class, and `x` isn't declared either...)

Comment: It is _really_ unclear what your end goal is. It appears you're trying to build a (de)serializer of some sort. Have you considered using an existing API? Also, you can use `someInstance.GetType()` instead of `typeof(TypeHere)`, or generics.

Comment: I want the base class to be a general class, so I can use the fromStream method with all the derived classes, so when I call fromStream in the main using the base class object, I want to use that object in the fromStream method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the method `FromStream` is checking the `properties` of an object, I think you could use `generics`.

Example Code:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual object FromStream<T>(string line)
    {
        string name, type;

        List<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(typeof(T).GetProperties()); 

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            type = prop.PropertyType.ToString();
            name = prop.Name;

            Console.WriteLine(name + " as " + type);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class MyClass : BaseClass
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

To consume:

```
var myclass = new MyClass();
myclass.FromStream<MyClass>("some string");
```

Any `type` of which the properties needs to be checked can be passed in by doing so:

```
public virtual object FromStream<T>(string line)
```

---

**EDIT**: Please also note that you can follow the approach mentioned by @Jon Skeet - i.e to use `GetType().GetProperties()`

In that case you could write the `FromStream` method as below:

```
public virtual object FromStream(string line)
{
    string name, type;

    List<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(GetType().GetProperties()); 

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        type = prop.PropertyType.ToString();
        name = prop.Name;

        Console.WriteLine(name + " as " + type);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: that's working great, thanks